# Existence of a canonical map of quadratic forms

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

For $X=\mathbb C^N\oplus \mathbb C^N$ equipped with a real structure $J^2=1$ and symplectic structure $S$ satisfying
$$J(z_1,z_2)=(\bar z_2,\bar z_1),~~~~~S(z_1,z_2)=(z_1,-z_2)$$
we see that $X$ has the structure of an $N$-dimensional Kahler vector space, and we can define the class $\mathcal A$ of real-valued quadratic forms on $X$, represented by block matrices as $M(z,w)\equiv z^\dagger Mw$:
$$\mathcal A \equiv \{M~|~M(z,w)\in \mathbb R\}$$
Note that we can write 
$$\mathcal A=\left\{M\in M_{2N}(\mathbb C)~\bigg|~M=\begin{bmatrix}A&B^\dagger\\B&A^T\end{bmatrix},~~~A~~\text{Hermitian}\right\}$$
We now consider a subclass of these quadratic forms which are of the form
$$\mathcal B\equiv \left\{M\in M_{2N}(\mathbb C)~\bigg|~M=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&A^T\end{bmatrix},~~~A~~\text{Hermitian}\right\}$$

what is the nicest surjective map $\mathcal A\to \mathcal B$, representable by conjugation by a symplectic matrix, that you can come up with? In other words, we want, for each $M\in \mathcal A$, a symplectic matrix $S_M$ such that $S_MMS_M^*\in
\mathcal B$.

**Motivation**: this would represent a canonical reduction of a quadratic quantum field theory to a non-interacting quantum field theory.

Comment: You should clarify that you want, for each $M\in \mathcal{A}$, a symplectic matrix $S_M$ such that $S_M M S_M^*\in \mathcal{B}$.  The way I read it initially it looked like you want a conjugation by a single matrix to represent your map.

Comment: Gotcha - I'll edit it now. Thanks for the feedback!